# Suppress OpenMP debug messages when running Tensorflow on CPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, openmp

When running a Python program on Linux that includes `import tensorflow` (installed without GPU support), a bunch of OpenMP debug messages are written to stdout, even when no functions from the tensorflow module are ever called. Here's an excerpt:

```
OMP: Info #212: KMP_AFFINITY: decoding x2APIC ids.
OMP: Info #210: KMP_AFFINITY: Affinity capable, using global cpuid leaf 11 info
OMP: Info #154: KMP_AFFINITY: Initial OS proc set respected: 0-3
OMP: Info #156: KMP_AFFINITY: 4 available OS procs
OMP: Info #157: KMP_AFFINITY: Uniform topology
```

Setting `os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'` before importing tensorflow does not get rid of these messages, how can I suppress them (from Python)?

Comment: Adding to @ivan_pozdeev 's answer: If you have multiple called scripts where you access tensorflow you can set `export KMP_WARNINGS=FALSE` to pass it to all processes within your bash-session (if you don't want to have it global or do not have the privileges to do so).

Answer (score 7):

Bottom line: **Set the `KMP_WARNINGS` envvar to a false value (`0`,`FALSE`, `off` or `no`).**

(If you use a multiple process setup, make sure to do this before you spawn child processes so that they inherit it.)

---

Googling `"Affinity capable, using global cpuid leaf"` (with quotes -- i.e. as a full phrase) finds https://github.com/catboost/catboost/blob/master/contrib/libs/cxxsupp/openmp/i18n/en_US.txt . It's a part of an OpenMP implementation. This code is not a part of tensorflow (and searching within https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow specifically for the phrase or a submodule reference named "openmp" finds nothing) but this is understandable because OpenMP is a part of a compiler implementation (this file specifically claims to be a part of LLVM -- i.e. `clang`). This code may not be exactly what your program is using but another version of it, but we can assume that the general logic is the same, so we can use this code for navigation.

Now, [searching for references to the entity containing this phrase](https://github.com/catboost/catboost/search?q=AffUseGlobCpuidL11&unscoped_q=AffUseGlobCpuidL11) (namely, `AffUseGlobCpuidL11` -- this is the ID of the message), [then for a definition of `KMP_INFORM`](https://github.com/catboost/catboost/blob/15712cfa704413d51618455326c30f5764956be5/contrib/libs/cxxsupp/openmp/kmp_affinity.cpp#L1563), [then for a definition of `__kmp_msg`](https://github.com/catboost/catboost/blob/15712cfa704413d51618455326c30f5764956be5/contrib/libs/cxxsupp/openmp/kmp_i18n.h#L155) ultimately finds [the code doing the logging](https://github.com/catboost/catboost/blob/15712cfa704413d51618455326c30f5764956be5/contrib/libs/cxxsupp/openmp/kmp_i18n.c#L891). [It says](https://github.com/catboost/catboost/blob/15712cfa704413d51618455326c30f5764956be5/contrib/libs/cxxsupp/openmp/kmp_i18n.c#L902) that it only silences a message `if ( severity != kmp_ms_fatal && __kmp_generate_warnings == kmp_warnings_off )`. Looking through references to `__kmp_generate_warnings` to find where it's assigned finds https://github.com/catboost/catboost/blob/15712cfa704413d51618455326c30f5764956be5/contrib/libs/cxxsupp/openmp/kmp_settings.c#L944 and looking for `__kmp_stg_parse_warnings` finds https://github.com/catboost/catboost/blob/15712cfa704413d51618455326c30f5764956be5/contrib/libs/cxxsupp/openmp/kmp_settings.c#L4514 which suggests that `name` is `"KMP_WARNINGS"`.

At this point, I assumed that this name should be documented. So googling for it will tell me faster how that "KMP_WARNINGS" is supposed to be set by the user and what the allowed values for it are. I was disappointed -- [no official documentation comes up](https://www.google.com/search?nq=OpenMP%20documentation%20%22KMP_WARNINGS%22). [Another result](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-math-kernel-library/topic/360825) suggests though that it's an envvar, and valid values are: *"Use "0", "FALSE". ".F.", "off", "no" as false values, "1", "TRUE", ".T.", "on", "yes" as true values."* The source code also uses `kmp_warnings_low` as a possible value but the name `__kmp_stg_parse_bool` suggests that no, the user can only provide a "true" and "false" value, nothing else. The above filter criterion says that nothing but `kmp_warnings_off` would have an effect anyway, and https://github.com/catboost/catboost/blob/15712cfa704413d51618455326c30f5764956be5/contrib/libs/cxxsupp/openmp/kmp_global.c#L116 says that `low` is the default if nothing is provided by the user.

Comment: This looks more like the output from having KMP_AFFINITY=...,verbose to me. So check that envirable as well.

Comment: I am sorry, but I'm a bit new to Linux. I want to supress the warnings as well, how exactly do i set the KMP_WARNINGS envvar to a False value?

Answer (score 3):

As the other answer told me *what to do* but not exactly *how to do it*, I decided to add my answer.

If you want to suppress these warnings, you can do so by setting the KMP_WARNINGS environment variable to a false value. In code, you can do this as follows; in your script you need to first import os and then set the environ variable, like so:

```
import os
os.environ["KMP_WARNINGS"] = "FALSE"
```

Any false value works here as long its a string format, `"0"` , `"off"` and `"no"` will also work.