# Disable Tensorflow log information

Tags: python, tensorflow

How to disable log info related KMP using tensorflow ?

already tried using both `tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity(tf.compat.v1.logging.ERROR)` and `os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'`

```
OMP: Info #212: KMP_AFFINITY: decoding x2APIC ids.
OMP: Info #210: KMP_AFFINITY: Affinity capable, using global cpuid leaf 11 info
OMP: Info #154: KMP_AFFINITY: Initial OS proc set respected: 0-3
OMP: Info #156: KMP_AFFINITY: 4 available OS procs
OMP: Info #157: KMP_AFFINITY: Uniform topology
OMP: Info #179: KMP_AFFINITY: 1 packages x 4 cores/pkg x 1 threads/core (4 total cores)
OMP: Info #214: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc to physical thread map:
OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 0 maps to package 0 core 0 
OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 1 maps to package 0 core 1 
OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 2 maps to package 0 core 2 
OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 3 maps to package 0 core 3 
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6121 tid 6121 thread 0 bound to OS proc set 0
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6121 tid 6229 thread 1 bound to OS proc set 1
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6121 tid 6431 thread 2 bound to OS proc set 2
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6121 tid 6432 thread 3 bound to OS proc set 3
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6121 tid 6433 thread 4 bound to OS proc set 0
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6121 tid 6228 thread 5 bound to OS proc set 1
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6121 tid 6435 thread 7 bound to OS proc set 3
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6121 tid 6436 thread 8 bound to OS proc set 0
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6121 tid 6434 thread 6 bound to OS proc set 2
```

want to ignore all the related info

Comment: Are those Intel OpenMp logs instead of tensorflow logs? https://software.intel.com/en-us/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference-thread-affinity-interface-linux-and-windows `KMP_AFFINITY`

Comment: I suppose this is what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56085015/suppress-openmp-debug-messages-when-running-tensorflow-on-cpu

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using this code

```
import os
os.environ['KMP_WARNINGS'] = '0'
```

0 means turn off