# Weird output when using TensorFlow backend on Keras (OMP: Info #xx KMP_AFFINITY)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Im using Keras with a TensorFlow backend to train a neural networks model. It is a simple model (from a tutorial) and everything works fine. Model predicts the way it should. Only tensorflow seems to be outputting information, and I don't know if I can safely ignore it/what it means. Can somebody explain me what the following output tells us? Especially all the lines which start with `OMP` are unclear to me. The deprecation warning does not really worry me.

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
OMP: Info #212: KMP_AFFINITY: decoding x2APIC ids.
OMP: Info #210: KMP_AFFINITY: Affinity capable, using global cpuid leaf 11 info
OMP: Info #154: KMP_AFFINITY: Initial OS proc set respected: 0-7
OMP: Info #156: KMP_AFFINITY: 8 available OS procs
OMP: Info #157: KMP_AFFINITY: Uniform topology
OMP: Info #179: KMP_AFFINITY: 1 packages x 4 cores/pkg x 2 threads/core (4 total cores)
OMP: Info #214: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc to physical thread map:
OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 0 maps to package 0 core 0 thread 0 
OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 1 maps to package 0 core 0 thread 1 
OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 2 maps to package 0 core 1 thread 0 
OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 3 maps to package 0 core 1 thread 1 
OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 4 maps to package 0 core 2 thread 0 
OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 5 maps to package 0 core 2 thread 1 
OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 6 maps to package 0 core 3 thread 0 
OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 7 maps to package 0 core 3 thread 1 
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 14400 tid 5252 thread 0 bound to OS proc set 0
WARNING: Logging before flag parsing goes to stderr.
W0820 14:05:56.256548  5252 deprecation.py:323] From C:\Users\Gebruiker\Anaconda3\envs\Anaconda3.7\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_impl.py:180: add_dispatch_support.<locals>.wrapper (from tensorflow.python.ops.array_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.where in 2.0, which has the same broadcast rule as np.where
2019-08-20 14:05:56.449349: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:145] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with Intel(R) MKL-DNN to use the following CPU instructions in performance critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in non-MKL-DNN operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2019-08-20 14:05:56.451182: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/process_util.cc:115] Creating new thread pool with default inter op setting: 8. Tune using inter_op_parallelism_threads for best performance.
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 14400 tid 13256 thread 1 bound to OS proc set 2
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 14400 tid 5064 thread 2 bound to OS proc set 4
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 14400 tid 8904 thread 3 bound to OS proc set 6
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 14400 tid 9408 thread 4 bound to OS proc set 1
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 14400 tid 14360 thread 5 bound to OS proc set 3
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 14400 tid 14616 thread 6 bound to OS proc set 5
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 14400 tid 2692 thread 7 bound to OS proc set 7
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 14400 tid 14172 thread 8 bound to OS proc set 0
```

Comment: In addtition, check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56085015/suppress-openmp-debug-messages-when-running-tensorflow-on-cpu/59838005#59838005 this answer where I explain how you suppress the OMP info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OpenMP is binding threads to your cpu to run. It is just logistical output I wouldn't worry about it. You can find similar output documented [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-kmp-affinity-to-create-openmp-thread-mapping-to-os-proc-ids).

> The Intel® Compiler's OpenMP* runtime library has ability to bind OpenMP* threads to physical processing units.
>
> This article will show you how to use KMP_AFFINITY environment
>   variable extensions from the Intel Compiler, the high-level affinity
>   interface, to determine the machine topology and assigns OpenMP*
>   threads to the processors based upon their physical location in the
>   machine.
>
> Example 1:
>
> You have one quad core system with Intel® Hyper-Threading Technology
>   (Intel®HT Technology) enabled.  By default, Intel compiler OpenMP*
>   runtime libraries will create 8 threads, running freely on 8 logical
>   processors provided by the operating system.

As described above in the article based on your physical CPU configuration the threads are assigned to different cores.

Comment: If you craft your response into a full-fletched answer with some more information included, I will make sure to accept it. Link answers are often frowned upon, as links might go broken over time.

Comment: to suppress these messages:
 import os
os.environ["KMP_WARNINGS"] = "FALSE"